# Angular http Api Response Cache (request just once)

Tags: angular, api, http, caching

I am doing a project in which I consume an api to obtain orders, the thing is that every time I navigate to another section and go back to where the api is being consumed, it repeats the request. I want it to consult the api ONCE it enters that section, and if I go to another and come back, it won't call the api again. I tried with shareplay, the method is ObtenerOrdenXOperario", I leave you a screenshot of the console, the service and the component:

[image]

[Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHV5z.png):

```js
console.log(this.foundRol. RolName); 
    this.authService
      .ObtenerOrdenXOperario(usuario, where)
      .subscribe ((response) => { 
        if (response) { ´
          response.forEach((element) => { 
            if (element. Proceso === 'ACTIVA') { 
              if (this.interval) {
                clearInterval(this.interval);
              }
              const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = { 
                state: {
                  orden: element, 
                  estadoorden: element.Estado, 
                  manual: false,
                },
              };
```

[Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7bgw.png):

```js
ObtenerOrdenxOperario(idusuario, where): Observable <any> {
    let params = new HttpParams().set("IdUsuario", idUsuario).set("Where", where) 
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
    return this.httpclient.get(environment.urlColector + "/ 
    obtenerOrdenxOperario", { headers: headers, params: params }).pipe(
    shareReplay(1),
  )
};
```

Comment: Hello welcome to SO. This question is a bit too broad, there are multiple solutions you can implement to do so. You can store your data, and check if it's stored before calling your API, you can try to implement some kind of singleton pattern, ... etc. You should try to explain why you need that API called only once, to be more precise.

Comment: Can you please tell me or show me the code ? How should i do it? I'm a newbie in angular

Comment: I don't understand what you"re trying to do. If you want to cache your api response you should check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65605654/how-to-cache-an-api-response

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.